How can I get nextauth session data in a server component?
I'd like to get the session data inside the /protected/page.tsx but I'm getting null, How can I solve this? Is it possible to get it even if it's a server component?
/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import type { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth"
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: 'XXX',
      clientSecret: 'XXX',
    }),
    Credentials({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize (credentials) {
        const user = { id: 1, name: 'User' }
        if (user) {
          return Promise.resolve(user);
        } else {
          return Promise.resolve(null);
        }
      }
    })
  ],
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }

/protected/page.tsx
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next"
import { authOptions } from "@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route"

export default async function Page() {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions)
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(session, null, 2)}</pre>
}


You get null because you are signed out. sign in from localhost:3000/api/auth/signin

You need to place the authorize callback inside a callbacks object under the providers object like so.
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
     clientId: 'XXX',
     clientSecret: 'XXX',
    }),
    Credentials({
      name: 'Credentials',
       credentials: {
         username: { label: "Username", type: "text" },
         password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
       },
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async authorize (credentials) {
      const user = { id: 1, name: 'User' }
      if (user) {
        return user
      } 
      return null
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.id = user.id;
      return session;
    },
  } 
}

And also make sure you add the session callback so the information you added in previous callbacks become available in the session
